# def show_batch( ) not showing my train images

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, tensorflow2.0

I am preprocessing data in TensorFlow following the instruction on their website: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images

However, after turning the images into tensors and assigning each of them to their corresponding label, I cannot plot them.

I load the pair (image, label) in parallel:
`labeled_ds = list_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)`. Then I check for the images shape and corresponding label:

```
for image, label in labeled_ds.take(1):
  print("Image shape: ", image.numpy().shape)
  print("Label: ", label.numpy())
```

And get
`Image shape:  (80, 80, 3)  Label: [False False True False]` as expected.

Then I define the following function to prepare the dataset in batches for training:

```
def prepare_for_training(ds, cache=True, shuffle_buffer_size=1000):
  ds = ds.batch(100)
  ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

  if cache:
    if isinstance(cache, str):
      ds = ds.cache(cache)
    else:
      ds = ds.cache()

  ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=shuffle_buffer_size)
  ds = ds.repeat()

  return ds



train_ds = prepare_for_training(labeled_ds)
image_batch, label_batch = next(iter(train_ds))
```

But when I want to display each image with its label using `plt.show()`, the images don't show. This is how I am doing it:

```
def show_batch(image_batch, label_batch):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
    for n in range(25):
        ax = plt.subplot(5,5,n+1)
        plt.imshow(image_batch[n])
        plt.title(CLASS_NAMES[label_batch[n]==1][0].title())
        plt.axis('off')
        return plt.show()


show_batch(image_batch.numpy(), label_batch.numpy())
```

Any clues on why my images might not be displaying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return plt.show` was inside the for loop. It needs to be outside like this:

```
def show_batch(image_batch, label_batch):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
    for n in range(25):
        ax = plt.subplot(5,5,n+1)
        plt.imshow(image_batch[n])
        plt.title(CLASS_NAMES[label_batch[n]==1][0].title())
        plt.axis('off')

    return plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Why did you add `return plt.show()`? [Official tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/load_data/images.ipynb) doesn't have this line (and it works!) - and by calling `return` on the first iteration of the `for` cycle, you don't allow images to display.

Comment: I have a problem with the plt.title line. It returns TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index